# Какие преимущества в использовании типа-интерфейса вместо типа-реализации?

Tags: java

В частности, в контексте JCF.

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
HashSet<String> another_set = new HashSet<>();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разница большая, Set - это интерфейс который лишь задает контракт класса в котором он будет реализован, что гарантирует этому классу минимально-необходимый набор методов. преимущество можно увидеть даже на таком простом примере:

```
class DataContainer
{
    private Set items = null;

    public void setItems(Set items)  {this.items = items;}

    public Set getItems()  {return this.items;}
}
```

У вас есть класс DataContainer который делает что-то нужное. Предположим что вам чем-то не подходит его функционал. Подставив другую реализацию интерфейса set вы сможете получить совсем другой функционал отличный от того который был у вас раньше, - например подставить ConcurrentHashSet использование которой безопаснее в многопотоковом приложении. Если бы вы использовали в сеттере, геттере и при обьевлении поля items класс HashSet то это сделать было бы невозможно.

Другой пример:

```
interface Figure
{
    public void draw();
}

class FigureSet implements Figure
{
    private List<Figure> figures = new LinkedList<Figure>();

    public void addFigure(Figure f) {figures.add(f);}

    // реализация метода того же интерфейса figure
    public void draw()
    {
        foreach (Figure f : figures) {f.draw()};
    }    
}

class Rectangle implements Figure {...}
class Square implements Figure {...}
class Circle implements Figure {...}
```

и их использование:

```
FigureSet s = new FigureSet();
s.add(new Rectangle());
s.add(new Square());
s.add(new Circle());

Figureset w = new FigureSet();
w.add(s);

w.draw();
```

Удобство таких конструкций в том что они очень гибки. Этот же FigureSet может использоватся в качестве дочернего элемента для других контейнеров. 
Все GUI на java построено подобным образом, - как большое дерево. Один базовый элемент интерфейса состоит из множества элементов поменьше, которые в свою очередь тоже могут выступать контейнерами для элементов. Перерисовка базового элемента приводит к рекурсивной перерисовке всех дочерних элементов.

Comment: Как я и догадывался, всё в угоду полиморфизму. То есть использовать это везде нужды нет.) Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: в принцыпе вы правы такое использование не панацея. просто нынче очень модно писать гибкие, масштабируемые программы с перспективой на будущее. поэтому такая практика процветает. с другой стороны если вы привыкнете к использованию интерфейсов вы найдете это удобным. лично я всегда привык использовать интерфейсы:  
`List list = new ArrayList();`

как-то раз работал не со своим кодом, где лист был обьявлен по реализации. я так удивился когда IDE вывел подсказку методов, первая мысль была откуда они там взялись :)